# @sys.person - Exctract firstname and lastname

Tags: dialogflow-es

Since April 18,2019 @sys.person system entity has been added :
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes#april_18_2019

It returns an Object: name string that contains given-name and lastname.

I want to extract given-name and lastname from the Object: name string.

I'm not looking for the simplest way that consist to split the string at the first space " ".

I'm looking for something that would comply with composite names like "Bree Van de Kamp".

FYI the processing has to be done in a webhook.

**Edit**: problem solved with "Bree Van de Kamp"
Now how to make it with with french composite names for exemple : "Jean Yves de la Héronière" where "Jean Yves" is the given name.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @clément-beaujoin

Comment: Yes I ask for given name and last name separately

Answer (score 1):

I have just found this service: https://v2.namsor.com/NamSorAPIv2/index.html

You could write some fulfilment code for your intent, and use the NamSor API to parse your @sys.person entity into a first and last name. it will also attempt to infer gender from the name, all of which you can then have a follow-up intent to check that it is right.

Comment: Interesting but it involves a call to the API and to spent money for a Pro plan of namsor. Anyway, let us know the results of your usage

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your webhook fulfillment gets passed an object, `sys.person`, containing `{"name": "Bree Van de Kamp"}`.

In this case, given-name and lastname aren't yet defined. You can set the values by splitting the name string on each space character, then running a for loop to reassemble the last_name, like...

```
let person = { name: "Bree Van de Kamp" };
let split_name = person.name.split(" ");

function splitName(full_name){

  let name = {
    given_name: "",
    last_name: ""
  };

  for(let i = 0; i < full_name.length; i++){
    if (i == 0) {
      name.given_name = full_name[i];
    } else {
      if (i > 1){
        name.last_name = name.last_name + " ";
      }
      name.last_name = name.last_name + full_name[i];
    }
  }

  return name;

}

// returns { given_name: 'Bree', last_name: 'Van de Kamp' }
```

You can test the above code block at https://repl.it/repls/HopefulFirstUnix

Comment: Thanks for your response that's what I did. But my problem is still here with french composite names for exemple : "Jean Yves de la Héronière" where "Jean Yves" is the given name.
The only workaround I found is to ask the user to write "Jean-Yves", but it doesn't make it with voice.

Comment: In that case, it might be easier to ask for given_name and last_name separately.

Answer (score 0):

In java I did like this :

```
    LinkedTreeMap person = (LinkedTreeMap) request.getParameter("name");
    String fullname = (String) person.get("name");
    List<String> names = Splitter.on(" ").splitToList(fullname);
    String firstname = names.get(0);
    String lastname = Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls().join(names.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```